# Add Comments to a Google Doc table

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

I'm developing an app.  I have a table in a Google Doc.  I want to add comments to certain cells of the table using app script.  I can't find any documentation on Comments in DocumentApp or Docs API.  Can some one point me in the right direction?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled across the same question a few weeks ago, and to make it short, this feature is not available at the time for Google Sheets and a feature request has been submitted  [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36756650?pli=1) (feel free to +1, it's old but hopefully they eventually develop a solution for comments).

the closest I got was creating the comment in the cell I needed and gather the commentID using the [comments.list](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/reference/rest/v2/comments/list) method and later on you can just append new information or rewrite it using [comments.patch](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/reference/rest/v2/comments/patch). Be aware, that you can actually create the comments from scratch but you have to create the anchor in a JSON format, I recommend reading this article about ['managing comments'](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/guides/manage-comments)

#### References

- [Feature Request link](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36756650?pli=1)
- [Drive API: comments.list](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/reference/rest/v2/comments/list)
- [Drive API: comments.patch](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/reference/rest/v2/comments/patch)
- [Manage comments and replies](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/guides/manage-comments)